# Form AJAX send inside a twitter bootstrap modal (Symfony2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

After trying every google and stackoverflow result for this, I've decided to ask for your help.

I'm building a Symfony2 app. Within every view of my app, I'm including a twitter bootstrap modal element, with a form that sends a suggestion/question mail. So, from my base twig template, I include this hidden modal.

Modal showing/dismissing works just fine. Modal contains my form, as desired.

What I'm trying to achieve from here is: AJAX submit of the form, mail sending in the controller, response to the view. With that response being json, and a success function to change html of the modal to "*dismiss_button*" + "Email sent" OR "There was a problem".

Seems fairly simple. Well, after trying most solutions out there, I'm not able to prevent the form from submitting. So I decided to keep it really really simple.

Here, the modal code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Send your suggestion</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}<p>We will reply to {{ app.user.mail }}</p>
    {% else%}<p>Don't forget to include a reply-to email in your suggestion.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <form action="{{ path("mgfbc_arrt") }}" method="post" id="arrt">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label for="username">Text:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea id="mail" name="mail" rows="4" style="width:500px;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" id="butt" class="btn btn-success" value="Send">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And, the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#butt").on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

After trying everything, I've reached the point in which THIS javascript does not prevent the form from submitting.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try giving an alert inside the script and see if that fires on click. If it doesn't fire then you need to bind this click event on `shown` event of modal. `$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {` [Source](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the on() function, instead use a delegate, try this:

```
$("#arrt").delegate("#butt", "click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();              
});
```

Comment: Don't use `delegate`, it's deprecated. `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method`. `on` will work the same way.  `$("#arrt").on("click", "#butt", function(e){})`

Answer (score 1):

@gomman Check up the following documentation: http://api.jquery.com/submit/
I think you need to cancel the submit-event of the form element to make it work the way you want.

@Fuser Although delegate() is a bit more readable to me, using on() or delegate() will do the same for this case. Citing jQuery documentation "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation."

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<form action="{{ path("mgfbc_arrt") }}" method="post" id="arrt">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="username">Text:</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea id="mail" name="mail" rows="4" style="width:500px;"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" id="butt" class="btn btn-success" value="Send">
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#arrt").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```